# Force Data Cache Miss

Tags: caching

I'm trying to write some simple code to try and force DCache misses.
Currently the idea I have is write a loop to try and empty the cache, and then call a few addresses that haven't been stored.

The goal is to fill the cache with data that I put there, and then force the cache to miss.

This seems to be very unproductive, and far from perfect.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Finally you could force a data cache miss? It could help me so much. Thanks.

Comment: After reading into it a lot, you'd have to fool the core's data fetchers into forcing a cache miss. Basically I created an Array of 64K cache lines, and lined them up by 4K pages. Then I touched each one once, and then either jumped 4 or 5 cache lines. This got me the needed results. I'll post the code in a bit when i have it.